# Sencha PHP Mysql

Tags: php, sencha-touch

Looking around my understanding, Sencha is purely JS based.

I am wondering if there is any way for me to use content from PHP + MySql driven website?

Answer (score 1):

In short: yes, through [XMLHttpRequests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest) to your server. Sencha Touch is a Javascript framework that runs on your *frontend*, since it's mobile probably on the phone your'e targeting. PHP (& MySQL) runs on a *backend*, your server. Your phone app would then access the website where the PHP-app runs and fetch/store data, probably through a [RESTful API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Zend_Rest_Server on PHP side and Ext.RestProxy in order to integrate SenchaTouch with PHP.